# mapping a row to rows from multiple sheets

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to read an Excel file that contains 3 sheets and I need to represent the data as follows: each row spans across all 3 sheets, for example

```
row1 = sheet[0].getRow(1) +  sheet[1].getRow(1) + sheet[2].getRow(1)
```

Below is what I have done so far but as you can see, the row is defined per sheet, which is wrong, I need this to get data from the other sheets as well.  How can this be elegantly done ?

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>> records = 
             new LinkedHashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>>();
for (int sIndex = 0; sIndex < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sIndex++) {
                // System.out.println(sIndex);
                Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sIndex);
                String key;
                String value = null;
                List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> sheetRecords = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();
                for (Row row : sheet) {

                    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> record = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                    for (Cell cell : row) {

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            key = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum())
                                    .getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()).toString();
                            value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            record.put(key, value);
                            sheetRecords.add(record);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            key = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum())
                                    .getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()).toString();
                            double number = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                            record.put(key, number);
                            sheetRecords.add(record);
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                }

                records.put(sheet.getSheetName(), sheetRecords);

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the outer for-loop to iterate the rows by index. In pseudo code:

```
maxRows := firstSheetInWorkbook->getNumberOfRows();
for (row := 0..maxRows)
   rowResult := new RowResult
   for (sheet := 0..maxSheets)
      rowResult->add(processRowForSheet(row, sheet))
```